# How to get actual user defined variable name in Python Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

From the given code snippet below, I tried to extract the actual user defined variable name other than the python built-in variable in order to check them agaist my naming convention rules.

**ast_example.py**

```
import ast
from pprint import pprint


def main():
    FirstName = "Johnny"
    LastName = "David"
    Variable_One = "Variable1"
    Variable_Two = "Variable2"
    Variable_Three = "Variable3"
    with open("ast_example.py", "r") as source:
        tree = ast.parse(source.read())

    analyzer = Analyzer()
    analyzer.visit(tree)
    analyzer.report()


class Analyzer(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stats = {"variable": []}

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        print "Node: ",node.id
        self.stats["variable"].append(node.id)
        self.generic_visit(node)

    def report(self):
        pprint(self.stats)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, after I executed the above code snippet, it resulted in not only the variables I wanted but also every python built in variables as well such as `self`, `__name__`, `open`, `source`, etc which are those I want to exclude.

```
{'variable': ['FirstName',
              'LastName',
              'Variable_One',
              'Variable_Two',
              'Variable_Three',
              'open',
              'source',
              'tree',
              'ast',
              'source',
              'analyzer',
              'Analyzer',
              'analyzer',
              'tree',
              'analyzer',
              'ast',
              'self',
              'self',
              'self',
              'node',
              'self',
              'node',
              'self',
              'node',
              'self',
              'pprint',
              'self',
              '__name__',
              'main']}
```

How can I exclude those built in variables? Thanks

Comment: None of `self`, `__name__`, `open`, `source` are keywords. They're variable names. The keywords here are `import`, `from`, `def`, `with`, `as`, `class`, `print` and `if` - and none of them are included in your list, as expected.

Comment: @ForceBru, ah sorry and  thank you for your feedback. I have updated my question to match with that already. I want to exclude those built in from my result list. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of visiting `Name` you might want to visist `Assign` which is the node that represents assignement.

So the code looks something like this :

```
def visit_Assign(self, node):
    for target in node.targets:
        self.stats["variable"].append(target.id)
    self.generic_visit(node)
```

Here `targets`, represents the multiple values for assignement such as : `a, b = 0, 1`

[ref: python ast doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#node-classes)

Comment: Thanks, but I got a strange exception `AttributeError: 'Attribute' object has no attribute 'id'`. Indeed, by printing `target.__dict__` it returned `{'ctx': <_ast.Store object at 0x7f699c4d0f90>, 'id': 'FirstName', 'col_offset': 4, 'lineno': 6}`, but could not access attrib `id` even though via ` target.get('id')`. Thanks

Comment: I found an error. That was because the last object of `target` did not contain attrib `id`. To resolve this, I used `try/except`, and it worked. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Sorry for that, I did not really test the code. You might want to check the `type(node)` instead of `try/except` but the idea is here :)